# Salesforce as database

Tags: api, limits, database.com

Is anyone aware of any licensing issues when using salesforce as a database? I mean something like what magentrix.com does. My initial thought is that if magentrix can do it then any regular user could do it too but it might just be that magentrix has a special agreement with saleforce.

Are there any liscencing issues when using salesforce like magentrix.com does?

Comment: What does magentrix do ? The question would make more sense to some if you explain things a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

You might be better off with [database.com](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/database/?d=70130000000lll1&internal=true). It is essentially the database component of Salesforce with similar SOAP and REST APIs.

Other than that, you would need to tread carefully if you intention is to bypass Salesforce user licenses through a single API user. Best check the license agreement around that you are allowed to do.

Comment: I don't believe that database.com is sold as a separate product for new customers anymore. You'd have the use force.com platform licenses which have a dramatically different pricing structure.

Comment: @ca_peterson Ah, I didn't know that. I don't I've every actually spoken to an AE, so I'm somewhat removed from what is and isn't available.